# PTC Heating Element Watt and Insulation Film | Hot Melt Glue Gun

Tags: watts, insulation, ptc, insulator

**Question 1**

If two glue guns of **20 watts** and **40 watts** are receiving direct current from the electric board **(no adapter)**. Then what makes one gun 20 watts and the second one 40 watts. Is it related to directly **PTC Heating element** inside? if yes how?

**Question 2**

In the image below PTC heating element is covered with some flexible packing (material) probably which is an insulator. The question is what is its name and from which material it is made?

[image]

Comment: Q 1 ... ask yourself these questions ... `how does power relate to voltage and current?` .... `how does current relate to voltage and resistance?`

Comment: Q 2 ... google `kapton`